# How set default name in the dialog with sent a xps print

Tags: c#, xps

I have to work on an application on a touchscreen so I do not have a physical keyboard.
The problem is when I launch a print with the command

```
printDocument.Print();
```

(printDocument is System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument)

in Devices and Printers I have Microsoft XPS Document Writer as default, so the dialog opens

[image]

How can I insert a default file name in the file name, for example 20171213Print.xps?

Thanks so much

Comment: Have a look at the Settings class. I think it is called PrinterSettings.

Comment: Yes I've already tried but I still can not do it.
Maybe I did not use the class correctly or maybe there is another way.